# Classification of common functions types

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm trying to classify functions types. The problem is that english is not my native language and I'm not sure if I did it correct. According to my classification we could have the following functions types:
$$ N! -> Factorial $$
$$ 2^N ->Exponential $$
$$ N^2 ->Quadratic $$
$$ N * log N  -> Loglinear $$
$$ N  -> Linear $$
$$ \sqrt N  -> Sublinear $$
$$ log N  -> Logarithmic $$
$$ 1  -> Constant $$

Is it right function types names or not?

Comment: So, what is your question? And what do you propose to do with $e^{n^2}$? and $e^{\sqrt n}$? and $n/\log n$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson My question is: Is it right function types names or not?

Comment: Good. But the question should be clearly stated in the body, not in a comment. Please edit your question. Also, why the "calculus" tag? I don't see any derivatives or integrals in the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson we talk about function and it is part of the calculus. Btw do you know answer to my question?

Comment: Functions are also part of Number Theory and Topology and Differential Geometry and practically every other branch of Mathematics, but you didn't use any of those tags, and you shouldn't use the Calculus tag, either. Anyway, I think the names on the right are correct descriptions of the terms on the left, except for "loglinear". That term is not generally used to describe a type of function. When it is used, it's for a function of the form $an^c$. See http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803100112734

Comment: Any thoughts, No Name?

Comment: Are you still here, No Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all look right to me, except for "loglinear", as I note in the comments.

As for $n\log n$, I'd call it $n\log n$. There is some (inconclusive) discussion at https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/76317/what-is-the-name-the-class-of-functions-described-by-on-log-n (which at the very least shows that you aren't the only one interested in this question).

Comment: @Thank you! How would call that function f(n) = n * log n?

Comment: Are you still here, No Name?

Comment: Yes, I'm here and I have voted up you comment

Comment: Good. You also have the option of voting up and/or accepting my answer (by clicking in the check mark next to it).

Comment: Have you gone away again, No Name?

Comment: You answer is not an answer. Your comment is an answer. So I voted it up.

Comment: Better, No Name?